# What are some pythonic ways to create a "chain-dict"?

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose:

```
dict_A = {'1': 'one', '2': 'two'}
dict_B = {'one': 'A', 'two': 'B'}
dict_C = {'1': 'A', '2': 'B'}
```

I want to create `dict_C` from `dict_A` and `dict_B` (Assume they have the same length). One could do this by

```
dict_C = {}
for k in dict_A: dict_C[k] = dict_B[dict_A[k]]
```

It works but I wonder if there are some pythonic or better ways (perhaps something like `dict_C = dict_B[dict_A.values]`, of course it doesn't work).

Comment: What is a practical example of what you are going for? It seems like there is a better data structure than chaining dictionaries like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dict comprehension and `dict.items` (although not sure whether it's *significantly* more pythonic; yours is good too!):

```py
dict_A = {'1': 'one', '2': 'two'}
dict_B = {'one': 'A', 'two': 'B'}

dict_C = {k: dict_B[v] for k, v in dict_A.items()}
print(dict_C) # {'1': 'A', '2': 'B'}
```

Comment: As long as the values of `dict_A` are guaranteed to exist as keys in `dict_B` (or their failure to exist constitutes an error), yeah, this is about as Pythonic as you can get. The OP's original code tweaked to use `.items()` (to avoid an unnecessary relookup in `dict_A`) is really the only sane way if you need to handle the possibility of missing keys in any way other than a simple filler value (the simple filler value case can be handled in a dictcomp with `.get(v)`).